# Xcode quitting unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently I upgraded to Xcode 11 Beta 3. Whenever I click on Assets.xcassets folder in my project, Xcode quits. Can someone tell me where's the problem?

Comment: Xcode 11 Beta is having issues with assets; in theory Beta 3 should have resolved them (*"Fixed a crash that could occur when using Interface Builder’s image inspector if the asset catalog contained a symbol and bitmap image assets with the same name. (51279661)"* from Xcode [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_3_release_notes)), but apparently there are issues; I'd suggest you file a radar.